# Safe to disable wptexturize?

Tags: functions, optimization

To optimise the speed of my platform (beyond caching, database optimisation, JPEG compression, CSS sprites etc),  it has come to my attention that disabling the `wptexturize()` function may give some minor results.

We can disable this function by using [this](https://gist.github.com/982554) script (written by our own "[observer of everything](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1306/what-type-of-machine-is-toscho/1319#1319)" toscho):

```
foreach ( array (
        'bloginfo'
    ,   'comment_text'
    ,   'comment_author'
    ,   'link_name'
    ,   'link_description'
    ,   'link_notes'
    ,   'list_cats'
    ,   'single_post_title'
    ,   'single_cat_title'
    ,   'single_tag_title'
    ,   'single_month_title'
    ,   'term_description'
    ,   'term_name'
    ,   'the_content'
    ,   'the_excerpt'
    ,   'the_title'
    ,   'nav_menu_attr_title'
    ,   'nav_menu_description'
    ,   'widget_title'
    ,   'wp_title'
    ) as $target )
{
    remove_filter( $target, 'wptexturize', 40 );
}
```

My question is, how safe is it to disable `wptexturize()`? When is this function being used? What should I consider when disabling it? The [codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wptexturize) gives an overview but doesn't detail when it is being used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`wptexturize()` (in `wp-includes/formatting.php`) tries to convert typewriter quotes `"` and `'` into typographically correct pendants like “ or «, depending on current translation files.

If you cannot type correct quotes, you should not disable it.

There are some related replacements for dashes and ellipsis (*not* localized for whatever reason).

All these replacement are done with expensive regexes, and they are not really safe. `<samp>$var["foo"]</samp>` for example will be changed, but it shouldn’t.

Disabling it does no harm, the function is not essential for anything else.

See also: [Ticket #19550 Please provide option to disable wptexturize entirely](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/19550)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is absolutely safe to remove the `wp_texturize()` filter.

Generally, it is only used as a filter callback. [You can see those uses here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/default-filters.php). Note that you'll have several `remove_filter()` calls to make:

```
$texturized_text = array(
    'comment_author', 'term_name', 'link_name', 'link_description', 'link_notes', 'bloginfo', 'wp_title', 'widget_title',
    'single_post_title', 'single_cat_title', 'single_tag_title', 'single_month_title', 'nav_menu_attr_title', 'nav_menu_description',
    'term_description', 'the_title', 'the_content','the_excerpt', 'comment_text', 'list_cats'
);
foreach ( $texturized_text as $text ) {
    remove_filter( $text, 'wptexturize' );
}
```

But there are other, non-filter uses as well, such as:

- [`get_archives_link()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/general-template.php#L825)
- [`gallery_shortcode()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/media.php#L790)

([See more here.](http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/wordpress/nav.html?_functions/index.html))