# Cannot understand WordPress error message

Tags: fatal-error, 500-internal-error

The error I am getting is:

Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'wptexturize' not found or invalid function name in /home/ifd6vop3yes7/public_html/thematchcandleco.com/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 294

Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'wptexturize' not found or invalid function name in /home/ifd6vop3yes7/public_html/thematchcandleco.com/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 294

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wptexturize() in /home/ifd6vop3yes7/public_html/thematchcandleco.com/wp-includes/general-template.php:1240 Stack trace: #0 /home/ifd6vop3yes7/public_html/thematchcandleco.com/wp-includes/general-template.php(1261): wp_get_document_title() #1 /home/ifd6vop3yes7/public_html/thematchcandleco.com/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(292): _wp_render_title_tag('') #2 /home/ifd6vop3yes7/public_html/thematchcandleco.com/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(316): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #3 /home/ifd6vop3yes7/public_html/thematchcandleco.com/wp-includes/plugin.php(484): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #4 /home/ifd6vop3yes7/public_html/thematchcandleco.com/wp-includes/general-template.php(3009): do_action('wp_head') #5 /home/ifd6vop3yes7/public_html/thematchcandleco.com/wp-content/themes/flatsome/header.php(10): wp_head() #6 /home/ifd6vop3yes7/public_html/thematchcandleco.com/wp-includes/template.php(730): require_once('/home/ifd6vop3y...') #7 /home/ifd6vop3yes7/public_html/thematchca in /home/ifd6vop3yes7/public_html/thematchcandleco.com/wp-includes/general-template.php on line 1240

It breaks the website.  I have searched for days with no results and I am at my wit's end.

I am a c# asp.net guy, not a PHP guy so I cannot for the life of me figure out what is going on.  As long as my site is down I am not getting orders.  I can do a backup to a version that works, but then I lose 50% of my woocommerce orders and I don't want that obviously.  Can someone tell me what the heck is going on?

Comment: This looks like a failed/incomplete update. You should try performing a manual update following the steps outlined here: https://wordpress.org/support/article/updating-wordpress/#manual-update

Comment: As Jacob said, first do a reinstall, but as always - disable your plugins 1-by-1 and retest to see if it's fixed. The next resort is to switch your theme and retest until the error goes away. That way you can at least find the source of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a rollback to WordPress 5.5.5 the hard way via FTP and running the upgrade and that seemed to fix it.  I then did an immediate backup of the site so I can roll back to that if need be.  I tried disabling all plugins and changing the theme in the database before downgrading and none of that worked so I can only figure it was something to do with WordPress core itself.  My understanding is that 'wptexturize' is a WordPress function that converts single quotes into double-quotes for some reason but not completely sure about that which is what made me think it was something to do with WordPress Core.  I will try and do a manual update to the latest version later since I spent all day doing this, lol.]

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at disabling the use of `wptexturize()` - check out this WPDevSE post [Safe to disable wptexturize?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/84497/safe-to-disable-wptexturize) to see if it will help your situation.